# Heroku SSL Endpoint Doesn't Resolve

Tags: ssl, heroku

I've followed the documentation in the Heroku Dev Center related to adding and configuring the [SSL Endpoint addon](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint), but I'm having problems accessing the SSL endpoint that is specified for me once the process completes.

Here's the output `heroku certs:info`:

```
Fetching SSL Endpoint gifu-3932.herokussl.com info for epic-real-estate... done
Certificate details:
Common Name(s): epicrealestatewebsites.com
                www.epicrealestatewebsites.com

Expires At:     2014-06-10 21:30 UTC
Issuer:         /OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=www.epicrealestatewebsites.com
Starts At:      2013-06-10 21:30 UTC
Subject:        /OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=www.epicrealestatewebsites.com
SSL certificate is verified by a root authority.
```

Based on this output, I'm pretty sure I should be able to at least access my application at https://gifu-3932.herokussl.com but it seems I can't. Have I missed a step along the way somewhere or is it simply a matter of waiting a while so that host resolves to the correct place?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it is just a matter of waiting a while for DNS resolution to occur. So, if you're going to do this, make sure you have 12-16 hours available to make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the provisioning of the SSL endpoint fails silently and never resolves.  You can work around this by removing the ssl cert with `heroku certs:remove` and then re-adding it again.  The endpoint should resolve to an Amazon ELB when it successfully is provisioned.